# Append to Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, swift, append

I'm a beginner in Swift. This problem is driving me crazy. Looking at it for a couple of hours now, but I cant solve it. Help is very much approciated!

I have an array of Objects. And I want to append Objects to the array. Each object contains of a PID and a NAME.CurrentObject is inialised to 'Queen'.

```
var stackObjects:[Object] = []
```

In the UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath the selected item has to be added to the array:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print ("Appending \(currentObject.name)")    // The selected one is printed

    stackObjects.append(currentObject)      // Append the selected

    for(var i=0;i< stackObjects.count ; i++) {
        let plop:Object = stackObjects[i]
        print("#\(i) = \(plop.name)")       // Here the array is printed
    }

    // Get the selected item for the next run
    let selectedObject = someArray[indexPath.row]
    currentObject.pid = selectedObject.pid
    currentObject.name = selectedObject.name
}
```

I'm not using the array stackObjects anywhere else in my code.

When selecting and printing I get this output:

```
Appending Queen
#0 = Queen
Appending David Bowie
#0 = David Bowie
#1 = David Bowie
Appending Boston
#0 = Boston
#1 = Boston
#2 = Boston
```

I was hoping/expecting an output like::

```
Appending Queen
#0 = Queen
Appending David Bowie
#0 = Queen
#1 = David Bowie
Appending Boston
#0 = Queen
#1 = David Bowie
#2 = Boston
```

Comment: could you post the entire code, i mean where your are setting the currentObject

Comment: currentObjects is of type Object and it values are initialised to "Queen". It is only set in the code listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### you are mutate your object after adding it.

arrays RETAIN their elements but don't copy them by default. For you that means that each array element and the currentObject reference the same object.
==> you keep reusing and modifying currentObject.

**either copy it into the array OR make a new currentObject after you inserted one.**

Comment: id make a new one after you are done inserting it once

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After some searching I found http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-beta-3-hooray which lists that in Beta3 arrays are no longer reference types (as one would expect). Now downloading Beta3. Thanks you!

Comment: aeh... you got something wrong. arrays reference content only - that never changed. this is not about the array itself but about current object...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Daij-Djan (prefereed answer) I have implemented a solution. This is done by creating a new object. This has to be done every time before appending the object to the array. To make sure that no linked object is appended.

Adding 3 lines of code, directly before the append statement:

```
let tmpObject = Object()
tmpObject.pid = currentObject.pid
tmpObject.name = currentObject.name
```

And replacing 'currentObject' into 'tmpObject' in the append statement:

```
stackArtists.append(tmpObject)
```